# PyQt5 to android with pyqtdeploy

Tags: android, pyqt5, pyqtdeploy

I'm trying to port my application to android. I run pyqtdeploy-build command, then I should use qmake on .pro file if I understand correctly. Here is a problem, qmake, make, nmake are unrecognizable.

I read there is some way to use QtCreator, but it was not explained well.

Guide I'm trying to follow: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/pyqtdeploy/building.html

Maybe there is an easier way to port my application?

Comment: Facing same issue.

Comment: Try to follow this howto: https://medium.com/@Lola_Dam/packaging-pyqt-application-using-pyqtdeploy-for-both-linux-and-android-32ac7824708b It uses `build.py` from the demo which demonstrates how to run qmake. There's no need to use QtCreator. I'm working on a demo myself: https://projects.scibernetic.de/frans/pyqt5-template - you just have to install SDK/NDK/Qt5 to make it work.